# Python efficiency query

Tags: python

So i'm learning to code in Python (haven't learnt another language before) and was doing the second exercise from: http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/15b-python-pushups/

I made a code that works but I can't help but feel there must be a way to do it with fewer lines, here is my current solution:

```
def check(S):
  a = S.replace(' ', '')
  if len(S) != 19:
     return False

  try:
     int(a)
  except ValueError:
     return False
  lister = []
  for i in range (0, len(a)):
     lister.append(int(a[i]))   
  if sum(lister)%10 != 0:
     return False
  if sum(lister) == 0:
     return False
  return True
```

number one:
Is there a better way to check that all the characters are numbers? I know the .isdigit() method but not sure how I would implement it, does this work?
    for a.isdigit():
       if False:
          return False

number two:
Is there a better way to check to condition at once using 'or', for example this part of my code:

```
if sum(lister)%10 != 0:
     return False
  if sum(lister) == 0:
    return False
```

can i combine the two somehow?

Comment: I believe this question belongs in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: A regular expression would be useful to check the validity of the credit card number.

Comment: `if not a.isdigit(): return False`

Comment: Thanks for the tip Korem, i'll add that to my favourites, and GWW thank you - will look into it.

Comment: Is there anyway I can summate the string with a quicker way than converting it to a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the lines to:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
     lister.append(int(a[i]))
return sum(lister) % 10 == 0 or sum(lister) == 0
```

The last line will `return True` if **either** condition is `True` or `False` if **neither** is `True`

You can also just iterate over a and use a list comp:

```
lister = [int(i) for i in a ]
return sum(lister) % 10 == 0 or sum(lister) == 0
```

You can also optimise further just calculating the sum once using a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
lister_sum = sum(int(i) for i in a )
return lister_sum % 10 == 0 or lister_sum == 0
```

Your initial check can check all are digits using the  [all](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function and [str.isdigit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) so you can remove the `try/except`:

```
if len(S) != 19 or not all(x.isdigit() for x in a)
```

So your final function would be:

```
def check(s):
    # split into individual strings
    spl = s.split() 
    # make sure  format is #### #### #### ####
    if len(spl) != 4 or not all(len(x) == 4 for x in spl): 
        return False
    a = s.replace(" ","")
    elif len(s) != 19 or not all(x.isdigit() for x in a):
        return False
    lister_sum = sum(int(i) for i in a)
    return lister_sum % 10 == 0
```

Using a try/except using [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
def check(s):
    if len(s) != 19:
        return False
    spl = s.split()
    if len(spl) != 4 or not all(len(x) == 4 for x in spl):
        return False
    a = s.replace(" ","")
    try:
         a = list(map(int,a))
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return sum(a) % 10 == 0
```

Comment: Oh and also, is there anyway I can find the sum easier? converting it to a list seems long winded.

Comment: @VimalKarsan, no worries, you could make more optimizations but getting the basics down well is the most important. I added a way to just sum once

Comment: @VimalKarsan, I added some extra lines I did not realise the question required the formatting also

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

- Your code accepts some inputs that it should reject. For example, it accepts 16 digits followed by three spaces, whereas it is supposed to validate the positions of the spaces.
- It's conventional (although not necessary) and usually helps readability a little bit, if you don't introduce things until they're needed. So for example don't create `a` until after you're finished with the checks directly on `S`.
- The `try: int(a)` code also accepts some things that it should reject. For example if the string starts with `-` then this check will pass, but then your function will throw an exception later when it does `int(a[0])`. It should return `False` in that case, not throw an exception.
- `if sum(lister) == 0: return False` seems wrong from the problem description, since there's nothing to say that `0000 0000 0000 0000` should be rejected. I assume it's not a real credit card number, but that's beside the point of the stated problem ;-)

In answer to your question in comments, yes you can sum more concisely than creating a list. The following is called a "generator comprehension", which you should look up in your Python reference:

```
sum(int(d) for d in a)
```

Finally, whenever you have a function that ends with:

```
if something:
    return False
return True
```

consider whether or not it would be better written:

```
return not something
```

The answer isn't *always* that it would be better, but it's certainly more concise.

Putting everything together:

```
def check(s):
    if len(s) != 19:
        return False
    # there's more than one way to check this, a regex is fine, but another way is
    expected_spaces = (4, 9, 14)
    for idx, ch in enumerate(s):
        if (ch == ' ') != (idx in expected_spaces):
            return False
    try:
        checksum = sum(int(d) for d in s if d != ' ')
        return checksum % 10 == 0
        # or you might prefer a one-liner:
        # return sum(int(d) for d in s if d != ' ') % 10 == 0
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Note that calling `int()` checks whether the characters are digits (and throws an exception if not), but that it accepts non-English digits such as Unicode `U+0660`, the "Arabic-Indic Digit Zero". The problem statement doesn't say whether this is allowed or not, but if not then you'd need an extra check with this code. On the other hand Matt's regular expression specifically tests for ASCII digits.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is much better than my code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to hard-code the required string formatting into array indices or regular expressions. You can just take the given format string and use it to parse the number. You can then check each character against the respective format individually and use the digits to add to the checksum.

Here's an example:

```
def check(s):
    # the format string:
    # "#" digit character, " ": space character
    fmt = "#### #### #### ####"
    # check length of input string
    if len(s) != len(fmt):
        return False
    # compute checksum and validate format
    checksum = 0
    # iterate "zipped" format and input string
    for f,i in zip(fmt, s):
        if f == "#":
            # expecting i to be digit
            try:
                checksum += int(i)
            except ValueError:
                # i is not a digit
                return False
        elif i != " ":
            # expected i to be space (but it's not)
            return False
    # validate checksum
    return not checksum%10
```

For reference:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: Thanks a ton - I'll keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

This will complete the exercise:

```
import re
re_credit = re.compile(r'^([0-9]{4}) ([0-9]{4}) ([0-9]{4}) ([0-9]{4})$')
def check(s):
    if not re_credit.match(s):
         return False
    checksum = 0
    for c in s.replace(' ', ''):
         checksum += int(c)
    if (checksum % 10) != 0:
         return False
    return True
```

Comment: You shadow the built-in function `sum()` by naming a variable after it.

Comment: @moooeeeep true, but only inside the local scope of the function and it's  the correct name for the variable.

Comment: Especially when in the context of advising beginners I would not recommend doing so. You could call it _checksum_ or something.

Comment: And this is a general problem, that unless your function is verbosely named `get_X` or `compute_X` then very frequently *one* candidate logical name for the return value is the logical name for the function. Such values are the sum of something, the max of something, the sin of something, a list of somethings, etc, whether you got it from the function or otherwise. The solution usually is to be slightly more specific in naming the value, if it's something that also has a function in scope to compute the same thing. In this case it could be `digitsum`.